# Badly performing query plan after adding ORDER BY to Full Text CONTAINS search

Tags: sql-server-2008, performance, query

The following query is proving beyond my abilities to fix - hope someone can help.

```
SELECT top 100 Id, Name, InsertDate
FROM Foo
WHERE CONTAINS(FooText, '"test*" and "hello*" and "goodbye*"')
ORDER BY InsertDate desc
```

Without the ORDER BY clause, the query performs fine (< 2 seconds). But when I add the ORDER BY, performance is awful (> 2 minutes).

The problem seems to be an incorrect query plan.

The query plan that performs well is this:
[image]

The query plan that performs badly is this:
[image]

IX_Foo_InsertDate is defined as: *CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX* [IX_Foo_InsertDate] *ON* [Foo] ( [InsertDate] *DESC* )

What is causing the change in query plans? How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the primary key please? And *full* table definition with indexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimizer is choosing the different plan because it thinks the benefit of having the pre-sorted `InsertDate` (using `IX_Foo_InsertDate`) outweighs the cost once you add the `order by` clause.

The optimizer cannot be perfect, it might choose a slower path even if statistics are accurate - but it will certainly make poor choices if the statistics are not accurate - are AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS and AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS on?

If necessary, you might be able to 'trick' the optimizer like this:

```
SELECT top 100 Id, Name, InsertDate
FROM Foo
WHERE CONTAINS(FooText, '"test*" and "hello*" and "goodbye*"')
ORDER BY some_function_of(InsertDate) desc
```

where `some_function_of(InsertDate)` has the same order as `InsertDate`